# [Azure AD]: Delete User Group Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, http-status-code-403, azure-ad-graph-api

I was Integration Azure Ad in my application User and Group i was maintain in local that the same scenario i was made in azure using Graph API.

The Create user, create Group, Add the member into Group and remove the member in group also working fine for me. but, the Remove group is not working. it's throw 403 forbidden.

The Sample Post Request is screen is

[image]

I was Selected all Application permission.in Microsoft Graph and Active Directory. and Grant Permissions.but, i also Get the Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

[image]

My Access token is

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkhIQnlLVS0wRHFBcU1aaDZaRlBkMlZXYU90ZyIsImtpZCI6IkhIQnlLVS0wRHFBcU1aaDZaRlBkMlZXYU90ZyJ9.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.liMUK4oOBtNuU-AFHr0VfwFxiIV57pMdha8oae2Xu7tKgQR8HeSTdKm7Ex4s7n7GSAF-2YATXMdFGF5vvfrlF3ALMH8zvENJwY8BOrVsB516z_BROVmagvAKuPWoByRrlDPrhsalJBwwcy_ex1bG-sWvGSBoMpKy53EGWzMt9IF9CSp5IiiVp5xHXHog8BV-P-Bb98smOrnrTK7WhO0ZMkDIUCbfF-4QySwAbFJaUSZPqdZXA8XE-rt7RLZGlpbSpAv5Lmzb2V4mAioO1eSKEjoYQApifCyNHg76FgcRx10PPt1HO2yN9z6s7RaH6H1C1BABJRPaO58SCJI-BsgjFg

Anyone Know Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your access token?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi My AccessToken is Updated in post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deleting directory objects isn't support at this time using application credentials.**

This applies to both the Azure AD Graph and the Microsoft Graph.
The only way to delete objects is using user delegated auth with a token from a user that has sufficient permissions to do so (generally an admin).

PS: I can tell you are using application credentials and application permission because the token you shared, when put in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) has an `appId` and `roles`.